# Retornar todos os itens JSON com forr

Tags: javascript, json, funções, loop

Fala galera, to precisando de uma ajuda.
Eu tenho uma function GET http e retorna um array de objetos JSON e gostaria de retornar os dados contidos nesses objetos, atualmente ele retorna  assim:

```js
{
  "name": "CON001 - Consulta por CPF"
}
```

porém tenho cerca de 10 objetos parecidos com esse e gostaria que ele retornasse algo como:

```js
{
  "name": "CON001 - Consulta por CPF",
  "name": "TAX001 - Exemplo",
  "name": "OPD039 - Consulta por CNPJ"
  }
```

segue o cod usado:

```js
/**
  *
  * main() será executado quando você chamar essa ação
  *
  * @param As ações do Cloud Functions aceitam um único parâmetro, que deve ser um objeto JSON.
  *
  * @return A saída dessa ação, que deve ser um objeto JSON.
  *
  */

const rp = require('request-promise');

function main(params) {
    // if (!params.name)
    // {
    //     return { message: 'Nome não encontrado.' };
    // }
    return rp({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `http aqui...`,
        json: true,
    })
    .then(body => {
        
        for (var i = 0; i < body.recordsets[0].length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(body.recordsets[0].length);
            var result = reult + body.recordset[i] ;
            return (result);
         }

    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

Comment: Essa request tá retornando todos os itens e você não consegue acessar todos eles? Tudo indica que é um problema no teu backend ali que não tá retornando tudo

Comment: Então, eu tirei o for e coloquei apenas "Return body" e retornou isso aqui{
  "output": {},
  "recordset": [
    {
      "name": "CON001 - Consulta por CPF"
    },
    {
      "name": "AUX004 - Prevent Screen Lock"
    },
    {
      "name": "EMAIL002 - Envio de e-mail"
    },
    {
      "name": "EMAIL000 - POP3/SMTP"
    },
    {
      "name": "CON001 - Consulta CPF"
    },
    {
    e etec...

Comment: Se tu fizer uma variável global do tipo array ali, e ao invés de dar um return(result), der um var_global.push(result) talvez funcione, tenta aí

Comment: até tentei isso também, porém retornou assim : {
  "error": "The action did not produce a valid JSON response: [\"CON001 - Consulta CPF\"]"
}"

Comment: Qual é o objetivo da linha *var result = reult + body.recordset[i]* ? não faz muito sentido somar esses dois valores

Comment: ela foi removida a minha intenção era concatenar mas não deu tanto certo, a minha real intenção é poder retornar todos os nomes propriamente dito ao invés de retonar = { "name": "AUX004 - Prevent Screen Lock" } retornar apenas  AUX004 - Prevent Screen Lock

Answer (score 0):

Você está dando return dentro do for, então ele roda o primeiro item do laço e retorna somente o primeiro valor, coloca o return fora do for, assim, ele todo será percorrido, ah e concerte essa linha, a variável result está escrita errado `var result = reult + body.recordset[i];`

Comment: Obrigado, a linha foi concertada mesmo colocando o return fora ele retorna vazio, Sainda:
Resultados:
{}
Logs:
[]